# vb.net creating and using namespace

Tags: vb.net, namespaces

I've googled for creation of namespaces and found some very useful examples, what these examples didn't have is how do I compile and implement my created namespace on my system so I can include it from my various applications.

So for example, if I create a namespace to load a config file from my application path and insert it to an array, Do i need to include the namespace on any project I use or is there a way to make it part of my environment?

Comment: You should accept answers to your questions.

Comment: I agree with SLaks.  Nine questions and no accepted answers is whack.

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking of Class Library (DLL) projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include a namespace that you created you have to add a reference to your project first.  If you have compiled your code into a .dll file, then simply add the reference to the .dll file to your project and then at the top of your classes put the "Imports [Namespace]".  If you haven't compiled your namespace, add the project (with the namespace that you created) to your solution, add the reference to it (under the Projects tab), and then use the Imports statement.

Answer (score 0):

When you start up a new Visual Studio project, select Class Library rather than Windows Form project. This will compile your namespaces as a DLL (exposing your public classes), which can be [referenced](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28VS.80%29.aspx) in other projects.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the concept of a namespace with the concept of a project, especially of a class library project.

A class exists within a namespace. If no namespace is defined, then the class still exists within the global namespace (the one with no name).

In any case, it's classes that do the work. Namespaces are only so that *you* can have a class named `Book`, and *I* can have a class named `Book`, and so that `TriDat.Book` can exist at the same time as `JohnSaunders.Book`.